# How to combine text-transform:uppercase with "normal" user text?

Tags: html, css, input, textarea, uppercase

I have some inputs and textarea with placeholders.

http://jsfiddle.net/k0o5k53s/

Let's say I want these placeholders to be in uppercase. I add "text-tranform" property and set it to "uppercase".

```
.cool{
    width: 50%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

It works, but now all user text is also in uppercase. So, my question is, how can I combine placeholders in uppercase with "normal" user text? I know we can easily type uppercase "MAIL", "NAME" and "MESSAGE" in html, and remove text-transform, but I wonder, if there is a way to solve this question without changing html.

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css for some explanation by the answer provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply uppercase only to placeholders:

```
.cool{
  width: 50%;
}

.cool::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cool:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cool::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cool:-ms-input-placeholder {  
  text-transform: uppercase;  
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2z84s2rz/)